# I am trying to focus on my main iframe video after click on other videos but it not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, video

I have multiple videos on my page And I want to set focus `$("#focus_video").focus();` on my main `iframe` tag on click on other video but it not working. After clicking on the video is changing but not focus on the main video `div`

My code:

```
<div class="col-sm-7 bannervideo">
    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"> 
      <iframe oncontextmenu="return false"class="video_container embed-responsive-item" id="focus_video" src="<?php echo $videoDetail[0]['video_links'];?>?rel=0&modestbranding=1&autohide=1&showinfo=0&controls=1" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay" allowfullscreen></iframe> 
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <h1  id="v_title"  style="font-family:'Roboto';color:black;"><?php echo $videoDetail[0]['course_title']?>
      </h1>
    </div>
     <div class="row" id="v_dsc">
       <pre class="secondline desc"><?php echo $videoDetail[0]['video_description'];?></pre>
     </div>
  </div>

<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4 col-md-4 col-xl-4 col-lg-2 bannervideo">
         <b>Up next</b>
          <?php
           foreach ($videoDetail as $vDetail) :
              ?>
           <div class="row smallscreen" onclick='video_link("<?php echo $vDetail['video_links']?>?rel=0&modestbranding=1&autohide=1&showinfo=0&controls=1",
               "<?php echo $vDetail['video_title']?>",
               "<?php echo $vDetail['id'];?>"
               )'>

            <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-2 col-md-1 col-xl-2 col-lg-4 pointer relvideo">
               <img src="<?php echo 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/hqdefault.jpg' ?>" alt=""/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-9 col-md-9 col-xl-10 col-lg-8">
                <h4 class="v_title n_title"><?php echo $vDetail['video_title']?></h4>
            </div>
         <?php endforeach; ?>
  </div>
```

script:

```
<script>
 function video_link(url,title,id){
    console.log("inside video link");
  $("#focus_video").focus();
  $('#v_title').text(title);
  $('.video_container').attr({
       src: url 
     });
  }
</script>
```

I do not know where I am wrong in my code.
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure focus is what you're after, maybe scrollTo?